# How to get JSONArray when this JSONArray exists but is unknown

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I need to get JSONObject from JSONArray “hits”:

```
{
    "total":28829,
    "totalHits":500,
    "hits":[
        {
            "id":3063284,
```

I do it so:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = response.getJSONArray(“hits”);
```

and everything is good, but what should I do, when I don’t know the name of JSONArray?

I tried to write so:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = response.getJSONArray();
```

But it says that () can’t be empty. But what should I write when I don’t know JSONArray name but it exists???? Is it possible?

Please help me, I can’t find any information in stackoverflow and other resources....

Answer (score 1):

You can view the [JSON Object Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject). It clearly requires key name for which you are trying to get the JSONArray.

If you don't know the key name then you can simply do something like this.

```
  val jsonVal = "{\"total\":28829, \"hits\":[ { \"id\":3063284 }]}"
    val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonVal)
    
    val iterator = jsonObj.keys()
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
       val key = iterator.next()
       if(jsonObj.get(key) is JSONArray)
       {
          // Your JSON Array is here.......
          val jsonArray = jsonObj.get(key)
          print(key)
          print(Your JSON Array here)
       }
   }
```

I hope you will be able to convert the above code into JAVA Version.

Comment: This “hits” will be unclear because it will have another name and can be dynamically changed. So I can’t hardcode it. I just need to become access to json array (that will have different name) , how to do it? Can you help please

Comment: @JalCreator the above code will print any JSON array in the entire json object. I have edited the code. You don't need to hardcode any string.